# React-native(expo) Where is the actual file writeAsStringAsync will write?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to write a string to a file like this:

```
filename = await FileSystem.documentDirectory + tempname + ".txt";
await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(filename, "hello world", { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingTypes.UTF8 });
```

but no files was found, and i need to use this to create a file

```
await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}${tempname}.txt`);
```

after that, the file was appeared at document/DCIM/myfile.txt. But i know using createAssetAsync will create a additional file.

I want to know  where is the actual file writeAsStringAsync will write? I use getInfoAsync to show the file was in

```
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540hkvega01%252Fstocktake-file-builder/456-2019-2-12.txt"
```

but i didn't find this path.

Comment: have u found any solution to this ? @hkguile

Comment: MediaLibrary caused me issues when using it to store txt files, if you change it to jpg you'll see it'll save, instead I used expo-file-system, I have an example of this in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460167/how-to-save-imported-json-file-with-expo-filesystem/71322708#71322708